# Why does Catherine refer to the kidnap as a "tiger kidnap"?

Tags: plot-explanation, happy-valley

In [Happy Valley](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3428912/) S01E04, Police Sergeant Catherine Cawood refers to the kidnap as a "tiger kidnap" ([script](https://subsaga.com/bbc/drama/happy-valley/episode-4.html) at 27:53):

> I need to talk to him about a kidnap.

> It's a tiger kidnap, it's live, it's ongoing, it's happening now.

Wikipedia ("[Tiger kidnapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_kidnapping)"):

> A tiger kidnapping or tiger robbery involves two separate crimes. The first crime usually involves an abduction of a person or something someone highly values. Instead of demanding money, the captors demand that a second crime be committed on their behalf. The second crime could be anything from robbery, murder, to planting a bomb. A person or item held hostage is kept by the captors until their demands are met. The goal of the captors is to have their risky/dirty work performed by another person. The victims of a crime like this are less likely to report to authorities since they just committed a crime themselves.

But what is the second crime involved? (Or why does Catherine think there might be a second crime involved?) Could this be a mistake by the writers? Or does "tiger kidnap" refer to something else other than what's described on Wikipedia?

(IMDB [lists this as a "goof"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3718780/goofs).)

Comment: Have you got a timestamp?

Comment: @Tetsujin: 27:53

Comment: I was wondering if it was possibly an eggcorn, typo from the unofficial subs, or 'misheard lyric' but no, it's accurate to the official subs too. I guess therefore, it's a 'goof', or conflation of events. The kidnap was initiated by 'someone else' for 'other reasons' - but that doesn't make it a 'tiger'.